# How to prove $\ln(1+x)\ge x/(1+x/2)$ when $x > 0$?

Tags: calculus

I think the equation establishes only when $x = 0$, so the condition should be x>=0. The first derivative of $\ln(1+x)-x/(1+x/2)$ is $0$ at $x=0$. So the inequality looks good to establish. Is there a better way to prove it?

Answer (score 3):

Consider
$$
f(x)=\ln(1+x)-\frac{2x}{2+x}=\ln(1+x)-2+\frac{4}{2+x}
$$
Then
$$
f'(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}-\frac{4}{(2+x)^2}=
\frac{x^2}{(1+x)(2+x)^2}
$$
Hence $f'(x)>0$ for $x>0$. Since $f(0)=0$, we are done.

Comment: When I was writing my answer I did not see yours. Should I delete mine?

Comment: @NiklasHebestreit Why? You just didn't apply the corollary to the mean value theorem about increasing functions, but essentially proved it in the special case.

Comment: At first I didn't like to prove it by using derivative of difference, but now must admit your answer is beautiful.  I tried to use series but failed to get a simple answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the **mean value theorem** on $f\colon[0,x] \to \mathbf R$ with 
$$f(t):= \ln(1+t)- \frac{t}{1+\frac{t}{2}}$$
where we assume $x>0$.
Therefore whe have that there is a $\xi \in (0,x)$ with
$$\ln(1+x)- \frac{x}{1+\frac{x}{2}}=f(x)-f(0)= f'(\xi)(x-0)=\frac{\xi^2}{(\xi +1)(\xi+2)}.$$
Since we have $\xi >0$ and $x>0$ we get the desired inequality
$$\ln(1+x)- \frac{x}{1+\frac{x}{2}}>0.$$
For $x=0$ we have $\ln1 = \frac{0}{1+\frac{0}{2}}$ so the inequality 
$$\ln(1+x) \geq \frac{x}{1+\frac{x}{2}}$$
holds for alle $x\geq 0$.

Comment: It is a different way of answer.

Answer (score 1):

To show
$\ln(1+x)
\ge x/(1+x/2)
$.

Since
$\ln(1+x)
=\int_0^x \dfrac{dt}{1+t}
$,
this is equivalent to
$\dfrac1{x}\int_0^x \dfrac{dt}{1+t}
\ge \dfrac1{1+x/2}
$.

Since
$\dfrac1{1+x/2}$
is the value of
$\dfrac1{1+t}
$
at the midpoint,
I'll combine the two halves.

$\begin{array}\\
\int_0^x \frac{dt}{1+t}
&=\int_0^{x/2} \frac{dt}{1+t}+\int_{x/2}^x \frac{dt}{1+t}\\
&=\int_0^{x/2} \frac{dt}{1+t}+\int_0^{x/2} \frac{dt}{1+x-t}\\
&=\int_0^{x/2} dt\left(\frac{1}{1+t}+\frac{1}{1+x-t}\right)\\
&=\int_0^{x/2} dt\left(\frac{1+x-t+1+t}{(1+t)(1+x-t)}\right)\\
&=\int_0^{x/2} dt\left(\frac{2+x}{1+t+x-t+t(x-t)}\right)\\
&=(2+x)\int_0^{x/2} dt\left(\frac{1}{1+x+t(x-t)}\right)\\
&\ge(2+x)\int_0^{x/2} dt\left(\frac{1}{1+x+x^2/4}\right)
\qquad\text{since }t(x-t) \le x^2/4\\
&=\dfrac{2+x}{(1+x/2)^2}\int_0^{x/2} dt\\
&=\dfrac{x}{2}\dfrac{4(2+x)}{(2+x)^2}\\
&=\dfrac{2x}{x+2}\\
&=\dfrac{x}{1+x/2}\\
\end{array}
$

so that
$\dfrac1{x}\int_0^x \frac{dt}{1+t}
\ge \dfrac{1}{1+x/2}
$.

Note that
the only inequality used
is that
$t(x-t)
\le x^2/4$
for $0 \le t \le x/2$.

If we use
$t(x-t) \ge 0$,
we can get an inequality
going the other way:

$\begin{array}\\
\int_0^x \frac{dt}{1+t}
&=(2+x)\int_0^{x/2} dt\left(\frac{1}{1+x+t(x-t)}\right)\\
&\le(2+x)\int_0^{x/2} dt\left(\frac{1}{1+x}\right)\\
&=\dfrac{2+x}{1+x}\int_0^{x/2} dt\\
&=\dfrac{x(2+x)}{2(1+x)}\\
\end{array}
$

so that
$\ln(1+x)
\le \dfrac{x(2+x)}{2(1+x)}
$.

The difference of the two bounds is

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{x(2+x)}{2(1+x)}-\dfrac{2x}{x+2}
&=\dfrac{x(2+x)(x+2)-2x(2(1+x))}{2(1+x)(x+2)}\\
&=\dfrac{x(x^2+4x+4-(4+4x))}{2(1+x)(x+2)}\\
&=\dfrac{x^3}{2(1+x)(x+2)}\\
&\le \dfrac{x^3}{4}\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Thank you for rigorous proof. It is good to know different thinking.

Comment: I think your answer is very good. If I had the right to vote, I would vote for you. Thank you again.

Comment: +1. This is [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) for $1/(1+t)$ with the uniform probability measure on the interval $[0, x]$.

Comment: So it works because $d^2/dx^2(1/(1 + x)) = 2/(x + 1)^3 \gt 0$. Nice.

Answer (score 1):

Bounds using the Taylor series can be used but it is far more work.
$
\def\lfrac#1#2{{\large\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$

> $\exp(x) \le \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \lfrac1{k!} x^k + \lfrac2{n!} x^n$ for every real $x \in [0,\lfrac{n+1}{2}]$.

In particular the one we need is:

> $\exp(x) \le 1+x+\lfrac12x^2+\lfrac16x^3+\lfrac1{12}x^4$ for every real $x \in [0,2.5]$.

Just comparing derivatives only works for $x \in [0,\ln(2)]$. But using a geometric series to bound the error gives $\sum_{k=n}^\infty \lfrac1{k!} x^k \le \lfrac1{n!}x^n \sum_{k=0}^\infty (n+1)^{-k} x^k \le \lfrac1{n!}x^n \sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^{-k} = \lfrac2{n!}x^n$ as desired.

Now take any real $y \ge 0$. Let $x = \lfrac{2y}{2+y} \in [0,2)$. Then $y = \lfrac{2x}{2-x}$ and all we need to prove is

> $1+x+\lfrac12x^2+\lfrac16x^3+\lfrac1{12}x^4 \le 1+\lfrac{2x}{2-x}$.

This is equivalent to:

> $(1+x+\lfrac12x^2+\lfrac16x^3+\lfrac1{12}x^4)(2-x) \le 2+x$.

Which simplifies to an obvious inequality.

---

**Notes**

The desired result is actually a [Padé approximant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant) for $\ln$, and *egreg* has already shown how to prove it directly. Note that it can be used to prove the Padé approximant for $\exp$, which is especially useful when we want an upper bound that the Taylor series does not give. Specifically:

> $\exp(x) \le \lfrac{2+x}{2-x}$ for every real $x \in [0,2)$.

Which in fact clearly follows from the above inequalities as well. So we have two methods to prove this upper bound for $\exp$, and it is a matter of taste which is easier.

Answer (score 0):

Take the exponential of both terms and re arrange the equation in order to be written as

$$1 + x \geq \large e^{\frac{2x}{2+x}}$$

Now you can use the Taylor series for the exponential, stopping at first order, to get

$$1 + x \geq 1 + \frac{2x}{2+x}$$

$$x \geq \frac{2x}{2+x}$$

$$1 \geq \frac{2}{2+x}$$

$$2 + x \geq 2$$

Which holds $\forall x \geq 0$

Comment: Thank you.  The answer is simple and nice.

Comment: @user1908842 You're welcome!

Comment: Oh, the stopping of taylor series makes the right side smaller, which breaks the inequality?

Comment: @user1908842 No. Suppose we continue up to the second order, we'd have

$$1+x \geq 1+ \frac{2x}{2+x} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{4x^2}{(2+x)^2}$$

arrange it and you will get

$$(2+x)^2 \geq 2(2+x) + 2x$$

that is

$$x^2\geq 0$$

hence again: $x \geq 0$.

Comment: @AlanTuring And what about higher orders?

Comment: @egreg For the third order the solution will be $-2<x\leq -\frac{2}{3}\lor x\geq 0$ and since we want $x$ to be positive, the result keep holding.

Comment: @egreg For the fourth order, we get simply $x \geq 0$

Comment: And so on, and so on.

Comment: @AlanTuring You need to *prove* it. But it's not sufficient: the fact that the inequality holds for $x\ge0$ with any truncation doesn't imply it holds without truncation, because the full series has a larger value than any truncation.

Comment: @egreg Mmm then let me ask you this: is there a way to prove the solution holds at every oder?

Comment: I don't know why you're keeping your incorrect answer up without even a notice that it is incorrect. You'll lead astray many students who read it. And @egreg already said that it's **not enough** to prove that the inequality holds for every truncation; you need convergence to claim that that implies the inequality without truncation. Finally, I don't think the inequality for every truncation can be proven easily without simply proving the original desired inequality, which is actually nothing more than the (1,1) Padé approximant for $\ln$.

Comment: By the way, inverting that approximant for $\ln$ gives the (1,1) Padé approximant for $\exp$, which yields the inequality you wanted to prove. But naturally this would be circular... See my (just-posted) answer for how to use Taylor series if desired. It's not that simple, but not so trivial either.